# how to require some npm modules into my js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

i have this index.jade file

```
  include scripts
  script( src='path of my site/project name/src/scripts/index.js' )
```

and also index.js file

```
var _ = require('./underscore');

var IScroll = require('iscroll/build/iscroll-probe.js');

var zepto = require('./vendor/zepto.js');

var morpheus = require('morpheus');

var easings = require('./vendor/morpheus-easings.js');

require('./vendor/zepto.touch.js');
```

I am getting ReferenceError: require is not defined 
I want to include modules for the correct working any help ?

Comment: are you using jade in client-side or server-side?

Comment: yes i am using jade on client side @lombausch what you mean by in browser

Comment: have you tried to use requirejs ?

Comment: that's not working for me

Answer (score 1):

First :

```
npm install iscroll --save
```

Then this :

```
global.IScroll = require('iscroll');
```

Answer (score 1):

The type of require you are looking to use is the node type. You can't use it directly in your browser. You need to get a bundler such as browserify or webpack, which would convert those requires to actual dependencies behind the scenes. [Here's](https://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-browserify/) an article that would get you started with browserify.